# Pivot table not showing all the df values

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
         CODE      STATION       PLACE               SECTOR   ALTITUDE MONTH  YEARS_OF_STATION
0        103036        NaN       TUMBES            COSTA NORTE      70  ENE       27
1        103036        NaN       TUMBES            COSTA NORTE      70  ENE       27
2        103036        NaN       TUMBES            COSTA NORTE      70  ENE       27
3        103036        NaN       TUMBES            COSTA NORTE      70  ENE       27
4        103036        NaN       TUMBES            COSTA NORTE      70  ENE       27
        ...        ...          ...                    ...     ...  ...      ...
4022090  117043  PAUCARANI        TACNA  SIERRA SUR OCCIDENTAL    4556  DIC       27
4022091  117043  PAUCARANI        TACNA  SIERRA SUR OCCIDENTAL    4556  DIC       27
4022092  117043  PAUCARANI        TACNA  SIERRA SUR OCCIDENTAL    4556  DIC       27
4022093  117043  PAUCARANI        TACNA  SIERRA SUR OCCIDENTAL    4556  DIC       27
4022094  117043  PAUCARANI        TACNA  SIERRA SUR OCCIDENTAL    4556  DIC       27
```

I'm creating a pivot table with this code:

```
table_years=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['CODE','STATION','PLACE',
                                                'SECTOR','ALTITUDE'],columns=['MONTH'],values=['YEARS_OF_STATION'])
```

And i have 371 unique values in `CODE` column but `table_years` is only showing 351 values. Do you know why this happens?

I'll appreciate any help or suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noted you have `NaN` value in `index` `STATION`, if you would like keep the original `CODE` then you need to fill the value with `fillna`

```
df
   index1  index2  columns  values
0       1     1.0        1       1
1       1     1.0        2       1
2       1     1.0        1       1
3       2     2.0        2       1
4       3     NaN        1       1
pd.pivot_table(df,index=['index1','index2'],columns=['columns'],values=['values'])
              values     
columns            1    2
index1 index2            
1      1.0       1.0  1.0
2      2.0       NaN  1.0
```

After `fillna`

```
pd.pivot_table(df.fillna(0),index=['index1','index2'],columns=['columns'],values=['values'])
              values     
columns            1    2
index1 index2            
1      1.0       1.0  1.0
2      2.0       NaN  1.0
3      0.0       1.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because there are `NaN`s in your dataset, you should specify `dropna=False`:

```
table_years=pd.pivot_table(df, index=['CODE','STATION','PLACE', 'SECTOR','ALTITUDE'], 
                               columns=['MONTH'], 
                               values=['YEARS_OF_STATION'], 
                               dropna=False)
```