# Pandas' table_pivot Generating the wrong number of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table of patients as shown bellow:

| id | exam | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 34.2 |
| 1 | 110 | 23 |
| 1 | 120 | 4.2 |
| 2 | 90 | 114 |
| 2 | 100 | 54.2 |
| 2 | 120 | 6.7 |

The `id` column is the identifier of a patient.
The `exam` column is the code representing a specific medical examination.
The `value` column is the numerical result of that examination.

What I want to do is pivot the table so that, each row corresponds to only one patient and the columns the exams. Like this:

| id | 90 | 100 | 110 | 120 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NaN | 34.2 | 23 | 4.2 |
| 2 | 114 | 54.2 | NaN | 6.7 |

I looked it up on how to do it, and the pandas library have the function `pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table` that does exactly what I needed.

So, after giving context to the problem here is the question. My original table have `884` unique exams codes, meaning the after the pivot it should result in `884` columns. But that is not the case, after I pivot the table, it shows  the correct number of rows but only `557` columns.

I checked pandas' documentation and searched for someone with the same problem but I couldn`t find it.

Anyone knows what might be the problem ?

-> [Original table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TIz0.png)
*The name of the columns were simplified in the example shown above

->Pivot code
`table = pd.pivot_table(results, values='valuenum', index='subject_id', columns=['itemid'] )`

-> [Table after pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKVeV.png)

Ps: Sorry for the poor English, I'm a non native speaker.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pivot table not showing all the df values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69277114/pivot-table-not-showing-all-the-df-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What might be going on:

Just guessing here, but I know that null values can mess with `pd.pivot_table` and cause values to fall out of the index or the columns. Maybe adding `dropna=False` to your `pd.pivot_table` call might fix the problem?

#### Examples showing how `dropna=True` might be the problem:

```
# Full data
data_full = {
    "id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    "exam": [100, 110, 120, 90, 100, 120],
    "value": [34.2, 23, 4.2, 114, 54.2, 6.7],
}

# I am going to pick on the example of id: 2, exam: 90, value: 114
data_null_id = {
    "id": [1, 1, 1, pd.NA, 2, 2],
    "exam": [100, 110, 120, 90, 100, 120],
    "value": [34.2, 23, 4.2, 114, 54.2, 6.7],
}

data_null_exam = {
    "id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    "exam": [100, 110, 120, pd.NA, 100, 120],
    "value": [34.2, 23, 4.2, 114, 54.2, 6.7],
}

data_null_value = {
    "id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    "exam": [100, 110, 120, 90, 100, 120],
    "value": [34.2, 23, 4.2, pd.NA, 54.2, 6.7],
}

datas = [data_full, data_null_id, data_null_id, data_null_exam, data_null_value]

# For each of the contrived scenarios I made above
for data in datas:
    # Build a DataFrame of that scenario
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    # Pivot as you do in your example
    pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values='value', index=['id'], columns=['exam'])

    display(pivot)
```

You will see that the exam is omitted even if the `value` or the `id` is null. However, if you calculated a unique count on `exam` beforehand, it would not agree with the number of columns in the pivot table.

#### Possible Fix

If you change the `pivot` declaration to `pd.pivot_table(df, values='value', index=['id'], columns=['exam'], dropna=False)` you will see that the column is not dropped.

I hope this helps! Sorry that I can't know exactly what's going on without the data itself.